# linear regression is not working in python statsmodel

Tags: python, regression

Why is this linear regression not working?

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

# Read data
cities = pd.read_csv('../data/useful/cities_of_census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island.csv')
non_cities = pd.read_csv('../data/useful/non_cities_of_census_subdivision_without_lower_mainland_and_van_island.csv')

# Fit
fit_cities = sm.ols(formula="instagram_posts ~ accommodations + visitor_centers + festivals  + attractions", data=cities)
fit_non_cities = sm.ols(formula="instagram_posts ~ accommodations + visitor_centers + festivals  + attractions", data=non_cities)

print(fit_cities.summary())
print(fit_non_cities.summary())
```

Can't get attribute summary?

```
line 16, in <module>
    print(fit_cities.summary())
AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'summary'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

A piece of data

```
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1         CNSSSBDVS1                CNMCRGNNM  \
0          13            21          Greenwood                 Kootenay   
1          22            36           Chetwynd     Northeast / Nord-est   
2          23            37          Castlegar                 Kootenay   
3          28            43  Thompson-Nicola M       Thompson--Okanagan   
4          29            44        Gitanmaax 1  North Coast / Cote-nord   

   instagram_posts  airports  railway_stations  accommodations  \
0                3         0                 0               2   
1                0         1                 3               4   
2                0         1                 0               2   
3                5         1                 0               2   
4                0         0                 0               0   

   visitor_centers  festivals  ports_and_ferry_terminals  attractions  cities  
0                1          0                          0            1       1  
1                1          0                          0            1       1  
2                1          0                          0            4       1  
3                0          0                          0            1       1  
4                0          0                          0            0       1
```

Same code actually works for another csv file. This one is a subset from that one.

Comment: You should see what `fit_cities` and `fit_non_cities` look like by printing them and their `dir()`

Comment: You need to use fit() before you can produce the summary.  fit_cities = sm.ols(formula="instagram_posts ~ accommodations + visitor_centers + festivals  + attractions", data=cities).fit()
fit_non_cities = sm.ols(formula="instagram_posts ~ accommodations + visitor_centers + festivals  + attractions", data=non_cities).fit()